# How to pass a files data from outside of application to a variable flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Thanks already. I stuck in this example for weeks.

in other examples mostly use apps own assets folder
I dont want to add file to asset folder.
I just want to get data from outside the app
and I want to assign this data to a variable

Comment: [`File('/path/to/file').readAsBytes()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/File/readAsBytes.html) will give you the contents for a file on the filesystem as a list of bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filepicker package will solve the problem [here](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker=) is the link
You can access file name , path with this package